# What are the letter keys in vim that can be mapped along with Alt and Ctrl?

Tags: key-bindings, normal-mode

Probably the most frustrating/lame part of using vim has been the fact that a lot of the easy-to-imagine shortcuts have already been mapped to something else by the developers...For some reason, `<C-F#>` can't be used as a keyboard shortcut, at least for inserting text.

However, the alt and control keys CAN be mapped to the letter commands in normal mode:

```
"enter insert mode and jump forward a tab
nnoremap <C-T> i<Tab>
```

Would any of you mind listing which letters, numbers, or metas can be used with Ctrl and Alt in normal mode keyboard mappings? Can those keys be combined with the arrow keys in normal mode as well?

Comment: I believe the answer depends if your are using Vim or gVim and if you are using the former which terminal you are using. Could you precise that?

Comment: I just mean standard Vim with a linux terminal with no plugins. Despite its relative simplicity compared to graphical IDEs, the keys can do a lot of funny things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the keys that can be mapped with `Ctrl` are those that produce a valid [C0 control code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#Basic_ASCII_control_codes) when pressed together with `Ctrl`. However, there are some caveats:

- `<C-i>` can't be mapped without affecting `<Tab>` and vice-versa,
- `<C-m>` can't be mapped without affecting `<CR>` and vice-versa,
- `<C-]>` can't be mapped without affecting `<Esc>` and vice-versa,

and, IIRC, `<C-@>` and `<C-j>` can be problematic, too, but I am not sure when and how.

With that in mind, you can open `:help index` on your own and look up which `<C-` combos are available in which modes.

For `Alt`, the situation is a bit more complicated because pressing `Alt+<key>` tends to produce different things in different environments. On Macs with an AZERTY keyboard layout, for example, pressing `Alt+a` produces `æ`. That is all Vim sees, which means that you can't map `<A-a>`: you must map `æ`, which may or may not be acceptable. Personally, the ability to type accented and special characters beats the ability to make `<A-` mappings in Vim hands down. As far as I am concerned, the number of keys mappable with `Alt` is zero.

To make sure, try a bunch of `<A-` mappings and see how it goes.

Comment: great answer, yet for me <C-i> does not seem to be an issue, i think using Ctrl with any of the meta keys, brackets, etc. is bound to be an issue since those have a lot of innate functionality. You certainly can't remap the Caps Lock to change back to normal mode as i have tried, Caps functionality has to be changed through the operating system.

Comment: I _think_ with some terminal emulators the protocol to distinguish C-i and Tab is implemented (and Vim responds to it), but I’ve never been sure of the details. Something about modifyOtherKeys, perhaps?

Comment: my vim doesn't like the modifyOtherKeys mode when it is enabled, im just testing out keys and seeing what works and doesn't

Answer (score 0):

I tested all the ctrl combods with every key in the middle of the keyboard, and these are my notes:

```
DEFAULT CTRL AND ALT COMMANDS

unlike nano, alt key is not used very commonly in vim
and doesn't appear mappable

C-Q is visual block mode
C-W used for making changes in split screen
C-E seems to do nothing
C-R is redo [an undo]
C-T goes back to previous tag
C-Y seems to do nothing
C-U takes the cursor to the beginning of doc in normal mode,
    but erases text from cursor to beginning of line in command mode
C-I seems to do nothing
C-O jumps to previous cursor position
C-P takes cursor up a line
C-A seems to do nothing
C-S seems to do nothing
C-D scrolls half of the screen length(down)
C-F scrolls full screen length(down)
C-G gives line and scroll(%) report
C-H,j,k,l standard navigation, C doesn't effect
C-; does "nothing"

Don't use quotes in mappings, because they prefix
a lot of commands

C-Z exits vim without saving, sends interrupt signal to
    any terminal program
C-X produces bell noise, only in vim.
C-C changes back to normal mode, don't map
C-V visual block mode
C-B scrolls back(up) a page
C-N brings cursor down a line
C-M same as C-N
C-, produces bell noise in vim only
C-. supposed to do nothing but don't map because . is useful by itself
C-/ produces bell
```